# How do I decrease the size of Icon in openlayers 3, i am using bing maps

Tags: openlayers-3

This is my code:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([-95.3698,29.7604], 'EPSG:4326' , 'EPSG:3857')),
   name: 'Null Island',
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: 'flag.png',
    height:10,
    width:10,
  })
});
iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
```

I have tried using anchor also, but I could not decrease the size, please help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`ol.style.Icon`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon-Icon.html) takes a `scale` parameter that you can use to scale your icon.

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: 'flag.png',
    // the real size of your icon
    size: [10, 10],
    // the scale factor
    scale: 0.5
  })
});
```

Comment: N.B. This is a singular value, not x/y individual scaling.  Really needs x/y scaling to be useful for some tasks.

Comment: looks like there still isn't a way to scale instead of crop using imgSize. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/2720