# Angular OpenLayers - Marker size

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

Is it possible to change marker's custom icon image size?
If i set inside style size like this

```
style: {
    image: {
        icon: {
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
            opacity: 1,
            size: [12, 12]
            src: 'images/map-marker.png'
            }
        }
    }
```

it only changes markers size on 12px x 12px but inside image stays in original size. 
Can i change size of image that I'm using for marker using directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found answer. There is parameter `scale` in OpenLayers3 `ol.style.Icon` and it can be used in angular-openlayers directive.

```
style: {
    image: {
        icon: {
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 0.5,
            src: 'images/map-marker.png'
            }
        }
    }
```

I used this question for help [How do I decrease the size of Icon in openlayers 3, i am using bing maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888025/how-do-i-decrease-the-size-of-icon-in-openlayers-3-i-am-using-bing-maps)

Comment: How to get coordinates of a point using [Angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) ,   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435689/how-to-get-coordinates-on-double-click-on-openstreetmap